# QGIS Azimuth and and Distance Plugin

Tags: qgis

Where do I find this plugin?  ( I am on v. 1.6 - it does not seem to be installed and I could not find it with the python plugin installer).
-Robert

Answer (score 1):

It should be supported on 1.6. In the Plugin installer, make sure you check 'Show all plugins, even those marked experimental' and try again.

As a last resort, you can manually download the plugin from http://pyqgis.org/contributed/qgsAzimuth.zip . TO install, unzip and copy the folder to the plugins folder. The plugins folder is located under the User's home folder ( .qgis/python/plugins/ )